# Is there a way to have change female to male voice during the conversation in DialogFlow (Api.ai)

Tags: voice, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We a building a chatbot app for Google Home using Api.ai (Dialogflow now) which has both male and female historical figures. We are using Actions on google. Google lets you default to a male or female voice when deploying the app. Is there a way to switch between male to female voice dynamically, for example, using code in webhook?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Maybe*. Although [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) supports a `<voice>` tag, the documentation for Actions does not list it as supported. However, as you noted, there appears to be some support. The `gender` and `variant` attributes seem to work, at least for en-US. The `languages` attribute doesn't seem to be. So something like this might work:

```
<speech>
    <voice gender="male" variant="1">male</voice>
    <voice gender="male" variant="2">male</voice>
    <voice gender="female" variant="1">female</voice>
    <voice gender="female" variant="2">female</voice>
</speech>
```

*However* what *is* documented as working is to adjust the pitch of the default voice (whichever one you pick) using the `<prosody>` [SSML tag](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml). Here is an example you can use to see how it sounds if you vary the pitch:

```
<speech>
    test
    <prosody pitch="-1st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="-2st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="-3st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="-4st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="-5st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="-6st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="-7st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="-8st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="-9st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+1st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+2st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+3st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+4st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+5st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+6st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+7st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+8st">test</prosody>
    <prosody pitch="+9st">test</prosody>
</speech>
```

You can also combine the two tags.

Comment: Thanks. I experimented and it seems though not published by Google, the message like:                                                                                           <speak><voice gender="female">
Say this in a female voice
</voice></speak>                                                                                                       this works - at least in the simulator . I will try your suggestion to make my voices distinct as I have 3 male and 2 female characters  and it would be nice to have distinct voices for each of them

Comment: Interesting! I didn't even try, since it wasn't documented to work. I've updated the answer. If the answer has been helpful, accepting and/or upvoting it would be appreciated.