# SSML Actions on Google, change speaking language

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, ssml

I can't seem to change the language during the conversation.
I tried:

```
<speak>
<voice gender="male" variant="3" langaugeCode="fr">
<prosody rate="105%">
Bonjour
</prosody>
</voice>
</speak>
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

The `<voice>` tag is not [officially supported](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) in the SSML for the Google Assistant, although it does appear to partially work.

Although the `gender` and `variant` attributes do [appear to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47315662/1405634), the SSML spec [does not define](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.2.1) a `languageCode` attribute (which you ask about in your question), and the `languages` attribute does not appear to be supported.

Comment: That is unfortunate :(. Do you maybe have any ideas how to change language dynamicly. Or it is just not possible?

Comment: @WinterChilly It looks like you have a typo in langaugeCode, it's working otherwise !