# google actions sdk: dynamic change in voice

Tags: actions-on-google, ssml

In the use case I am working on, I wish to change the TTS voice by passing a parameter in the conversation speech string. For example,

```
<speak><voice gender="male" variation="1">Hello</voice></speak>
```

The actions console mentions that we can override the user's default locale and **force** a particular TTS voice (as above). And it does work.

The question is: how do we set the voice to say: `en-AU` or `en-GB` via the voice tag? I tried setting it via `variation` or `language` or `name`, it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [SSML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.2.1) supports a `<voice>` tag with a `languages` attribute, this isn't one of the SSML tags that are [officially supported](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) by the Google Assistant. Although there is [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306477/is-there-a-way-to-have-change-female-to-male-voice-during-the-conversation-in-di/47315662#47315662) that the tag is semi-supported with the `gender` and `variant` attributes, the `languages` attribute isn't.

Aside from setting the region in the Action console, there is no way to currently change which region's voice is used for your Action.

Comment: for some reason when we introduce the voice tag after setting the base actions language to say `en-AU`, it immediately ignores that and sets the language to `en-US`.

Comment: Given the voice tag isn't officially supported, that doesn't surprise me too much. (Disappoints me, tho.)