# Change google assistant voice programmatically

Tags: actions-on-google

For most languages, the Google Assistant allows developers to choose from 4 type of voice as of now, 2 from female and 2 from male, for most languages.

I want to know the way to change it dynamically through node/java library.

I have tried with [actions-on-google-nodejs](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs#readme) but did not find anything in it.

I know we can change it either from google assistant application or from deployment setting, but do we have any way to change it dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Although not documented (except in [StackOverflow currently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47315662/1405634)) you can use the `<voice>` SSML tag to change which type is used. You can further adjust the pitch to create additional variants.

You can send SSML back using the actions-on-google-nodejs library by either including a string with valid SSML or by explicitly creating a [SimpleResponse](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.simpleresponse.html) and setting the `ssml` property.

The [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) library includes the ability to pre-define voices as combinations of the voice and prosody tags and will let you easily define which voice is to be used for each response.

Comment: So in that case I cannot use Actions nodejs library right? I need to make my own json inorder to use SSML tag

Comment: You **can** set SSML with the actions-on-google library. Answer updated to clarify.

Comment: Oh okay, got it, thanks for the update, will check it soon